# Regex: full path into Java package

Tags: java, regex, path, package, sublimetext

I would like to use a single regular expression to turn a fully qualified path (e.g. /home/user/java/project/src/main/java/com/website/project/File.java) into the corresponding Java package.

This means, I would like to remove everything before and including "java/", the file name plus a leading slash. And then turn all remaining slashes into dots.

I seem to be able to get pretty far by using the following match clause

```
.+main\/java\/|\/|[a-zA-Z$]+(\.java)
```

and replacing with a dot. (The regex basically looks for everything before and including "main/java/", then replaces all / with . and then removes the file name.

The problem is that I now have too many dots that I obviously cannot be rid of since I am replacing with dots :)

And since I am not too good with regular expressions, I am probably using an entirely wrong approach anyways...

I would very much appreciate any help.

PS.: Unfortunately, I need to use just a single regex since I can only inject one and not save results into temporary variables or anything like that.

Thank you very much!

**Edit**

I am trying to create a tmSnippet for TextMate / Sublime Text.
I would like to add the phrase "package com.company.project" (but with the actual package name, of course) automatically to new files.
The thing is that in such a snippet you can take the full path of the file and run it through a regex before output. This is why I can only use exactly one regex.

**Edit2**

I was able to do what I wanted by using a python script and running that as a command in Sublime Text.
For those interested, see this [GitHub commit](https://github.com/NeQuissimus/Sublime/commit/e96a921a88c831dd61bda6e6c2ceaadc72c68faf). I am still curious whether it would be possible to turn all this into a single RegEx. I am not even sure it is possible...

Comment: I believe he's thinking in Perl/sed/awk, where the slash is the regex delimiter.

Comment: Oh yes, I am escaping slashes as it is the delimiter...

Comment: in what language are you executing the regex?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you're trying to do and where you need to "inject" this regex, but the following regex will return two capturing groups, the first being the path to the Java file, and the second being the filename itself:

```
.+main\\/java\\/([[A-Za-z0-9]+\\/]+)\\/([A-Za-z0-9]+)\\.java
```

You can then replace `'/'` on the first captured group with `'.'` and then append a dot and the second captured String giving you the fully-qualified Java class name.

As i say, i'm not sure why you have restrictions of not being able to use variables but hopefully the working regex is a step forward for you.